# Contenttype with a repeatable section

Tags: bolt-cms

I am building my first Bolt website and I have been having trouble adapting contenttypes to my design.

On one page I have a list of various video and pictures each followed by a short blurb and a link, with each photo/video and blurb formatted nicely together in a box. Is there a way to setup a contenttype that lets an author create an undefined number of such boxes? I want an author to be able to enter a description, photo/video, and title and click "add another" and repeat the process as many times as they want.

The best solution I could think of is to create a *media* contenttype that has a description, media, and  link that could be selected via a relationship from the contenttype with the list of boxes. But I don't like this solution as the author would have to create and link a bunch of small records that would quickly become hard to keep track of, and I think the roundabout way of adding content to the page would be confusing to an athor.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is currently not yet possible in Bolt.

Your suggestion for a separate Media contenttype would work, of course.